# clojure returning hello world and nothing in the output

Tags: clojure

I just started learning Clojure and I have my own Clojure script but it's not returning the output that I am hoping for (`Hello World`). Here is my code:

```clj
(ns com.playground.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main 
  [] 
  ((defn CHEESE
     []
     (str "Hello World"))

   (CHEESE)))
```

This is the output that I get in the REPL:

```
clj꞉com.playground.core꞉> 
#'com.playground.core/-main
```

I want to see `Hello World` in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double parentheses there. Try this:

```
(defn -main
  []
  (defn CHEESE
    []
    (str "Hello World"))
  (CHEESE))
```

Of course your MUST call `-main`, otherwise you'll see nothing:

```
(defn -main
  []
  (defn CHEESE
    []
    (str "Hello World"))
  (CHEESE))
=> #'com.playground.core/-main
(-main)
=> "Hello World"
```

I see your define a function inside another function. You should use `let` or `letfn` for this purpose.

Comment: Now I'm calling main and I still don't see anything in the output.

Comment: You won't see anything unless you fix your code. @AlanThompson has a point here, you should review the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a REPL for the project does not run `-main`. *Running* your program produces the following:

```
Execution error (ArityException) at com.playground.core/-main (core.clj:6).
Wrong number of args (1) passed to: com.playground.core/-main/CHEESE--177
```

What is happening?

1. The `defn` form creates and registers a function under the name
   `CHEESE` in the `com.playground.core` namespace.
2. The `defn` form returns the created *var*, which evaluates to the
   function.
3. The containing `((defn ...) (CHEESE))` form applies the `CHEESE` function to
   `(CHEESE)`, the result of evaluating the `CHEESE` function without
   arguments,
4. ... which is the string `"Hello World"`.

It doesn't matter what the argument is, because `CHEESE` has no arity 1 invocation: you can't apply it to any argument.

You can get the same (bad) effect more simply by pulling the `defn` for `CHEESE` out of `-main`. While we're at it, let's drop the `str`, which has no effect:

```
(defn CHEESE []
  "Hello World")

(defn -main []
  (CHEESE (CHEESE)))

Execution error (ArityException) at com.playground.core/-main (core.clj:8).
Wrong number of args (1) passed to: com.playground.core/CHEESE
```

To put it right, we simply drop the `(CHEESE)`argument:

```
(defn -main []
  (CHEESE))
```

producing ...

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

No returned value, but at least it ran. But if we evaluate `(-main)` in a REPL, ...

```
(-main)
=> "Hello World"
```

There.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It's not exactly wrong.
This return is the "return of declaration".

For example, you defined a `-main` in the `com.playground.core` namespace.

The return is the symbol of this declaration `#'com.playground.core/-main`

To print the `Hello world` message you need to call the function `CHEESE` after the declaration.

[image]

So... about double parenthesis, it's not good, but not impact hehe.
Another point is the function name, it's not good too. Consider using kebab-case.

You also consider keeping the function declaration more explicitly. Something like that;

```
(ns com.playground.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn CHEESE [] (str "Hello World"))

(defn -main []
  (CHEESE))
```

But also did it you're not printing the Hello world. Your only declaring a function (CHEESE) that returns a String type.

To print, you need to call a print function.

```
(ns com.playground.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn hello [] (str "Hello World"))

(defn -main []
  (print (hello)))
```

I did the evolution of declarations to explain better

[image]

So, you can improve the code using the `let` alternative and the `threading macros`

Consider use the https://kimh.github.io/clojure-by-example/ and https://tryclojure.org/ to understand these options better :)